# Magento 2.3.4 Setup_Module

Tags: module, installation, magento2

Magento 2.3.4 setup_module table does not show newly installed module as well as most of the default modules?

[image: Database Screenshot]

Comment: Please elaborate the question by describing what you are trying to achieve and what you tried. Adding sample code and screenshots always helps.

Comment: It does look like you are missing some modules there. Just double check that your composer correctly installed the magento packages and you had ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade` afterwards. Also check the module status `bin/magento module:status` to double check the module list.

Answer (score 0):

Module register in setup_module database use Two file

> app/code/vendor/module_name/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'vendor_modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

And second file ,

> app/code/vendor/module_name/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="vendor_modulename" setup_version="1.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

After created file and run this command,

**php bin/magento s:up**

**php bin/magento c:f**

Hope the help

Thanks.